# Magento config xml multiple layout updates

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, configuration, layout-update

Can I define more than one layout update file in my config.xml for the adminhtml?

I want something like this:

```
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <blog_admin>
                <file>flinders_blog.xml</file>
            </blog_admin>
            <another_module>
                <file>another_module.xml</file>
            </another_module>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
```

But this is not working. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why you want 2 layout file where you can do anything from just one layout, and another thing for one extension you can create 1 layout file only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try my below suggestion for it.

```
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <blog_admin>
                <file>flinders_blog.xml</file>
            </blog_admin>
            <namespace_modulename>
                <file>another_module.xml</file>
            </namespace_modulename>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
```

Comment: Thanks, really simple solution, should have thought of that myself.